# Android SoundPool limit

Tags: android, soundpool

I'm not sure if I understand this limitation for SoundPool in Android:

> For audio, there's a hard limit of 32 active AudioTrack objects per device

I want to load much more then 32 sounds, let's say about 100. But play in the same time, only 5-10. Is this possible with SoundPool?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine. You can load more than 32 sounds, but you can't play more than 32 sounds all at once. However, there is a limit on the size of the sound files you load. Each file needs to be < 1 Mb when decompressed to PCM format.